# Can we get the specifications of all available Google Cloud virtual machines?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is there a way to get the specifications (CPU, RAM, storage, ...) of all available virtual machines ? I tried using the Compute API, but, as I understand, we only get the virtual machines that we are using in a project.

I tried their API using both their website and their .NET SDK, and both sent me `null` as a result :

```
{
    kind: "some response",
    id: "some response",
    selfLink: "Google apis link"
    // but no "items" element such as the element they describe in their documentation
}
```

```
ComputeService computeService = new ComputeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = GetCredential(),
    ApplicationName = "Google-ComputeSample/0.1",
});

// Project ID for this request.
string project = "fit-guide-347306";

// The name of the zone for this request.
string zone = "europe-west2-a";

InstancesResource.ListRequest request = computeService.Instances.List(project, zone);

Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.InstanceList response;
do
{
    // To execute asynchronously in an async method, replace `request.Execute()` as shown:
    // response = request.Execute();
    response = await request.ExecuteAsync();

    if (response.Items == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    foreach (Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.Instance instance in response.Items)
    {
        // TODO: Change code below to process each `instance` resource:
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance));
    }
    request.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
} while (response.NextPageToken != null);

public static GoogleCredential GetCredential()
{
    return GoogleCredential.FromFile("myPath/myFile.json");
}
```

But the thing is, I want to know the specifications of the virtual machines that are **available** for everyone, not the ones of a specific project on Google Cloud.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You use [instance List](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list) API to list all the instance. If you want the detail, you have to use [instance get](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get) API for that.

Comment: Hi, if I am not wrong, it sends you the machines you are using in a project. The thing is, I just want to have the list of all the virtual machines that are offered by GCP. Not the ones that I would pay in a GCP project.

Comment: Apologize for my misunderstanding. In fact, there is no API for that, because you can create custom VM, with the CPU, Memory, Disk and GPU that you want. There isn't a static list of predefine VM config as you can have on AWS for instance. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type

Comment: No worries. If I understand the documentation, I can create an instance and get its cost ? I could do that then delete the created instance as I don't need it in the GCP project. I just tested that, without creating it, as I have some "limitations" (school project). How can I be sure that I can create a virtual machine, get its price and delete it without having to pay anything ?

Comment: You can use the Cloud Billing API if you want to get the price by API. https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api